# Set and get variables among objects without referencing them

Tags: c++, oop

I have a lot of objects that are not aware of each other, but I need to exchange data between them (`set` and `get` variables of those objects).
How can I do that?
I investigated the `Observer design pattern` but it seems like that pattern can only be used when the observed data is similar between those classes.

In other words, this could be done as follows:

```
void ObjectB::setVarA(ObjectA &objectA) {
    objectA.setVar(15);
}
```

but without passing `&object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observer design pattern *is* what you are looking for. You can make your objects observable, and have an observer which has control over them. You can have different observers for different objects so :

> it seems like that pattern can only be used when the observed data is similar between those classes

is a misunderstanding. Check [this](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) and [this](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer)

you can notify the observers according to the different actions. For example when your obj1's "name" property changes, you can notify the observer as well as when your obj2's "date" property changes you can again notify the observer.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects aren't aware of each other and you want to keep it that way, then you can create functions that are aware of both objects as follows:

`void SetObjectBVarA(const ObjectA & objectA, ObjectB & objectB)
{
    objectB.setVarA(objectA.getVarA());
}`